# Magento 2: Same ID already exists

Tags: category, error, exception

I'm having this error when entering one certain category in frontend:

Exception #0 (Exception): Item (Magento\Review\Model\Review\Summary) with the same ID "519" already exists.

Any ideas what that could be about?

Comment: When you enter a category you have already set the category ID in the code

Comment: After removing that product with that ID the problem is gone so there was something wrong with that product.

Answer (score 6):

We have just had the same issue and it's due to the `review_entity_summary` table having duplicate records for that product id. 
if you `select * from review_entity_summary where entity_pk_value='519';` it will return two rows for the same `store_id`, if you delete one of the rows it resolves the issue.

Comment: Have you had it just once or is the problem coming up now and then? What's the cause?

Answer (score 0):

After looking on internet for days i can't find exact solution of this.
Then i found if we change the URLKEY of the category it will not show this error so i have done this.

```
$category->setPath($parentCategory->getPath())
            ->setParentId($parentId)
            ->setName('test1')
            ->setIsActive(true)
            ->setUrlKey(rand(1,1000000000));

        $category->save();
```

I use random function to add category in database with random no using  ***->setUrlKey(rand(1,1000000000));*** you can add any thing in this like duplicate category name with some random no etc.
and errors gone if it helps you give an UP. thanks